# Windows Service "Starting"

Tags: service, windows-services

I have a critical windows service that I need for my web application.

Unfortunately, the windows service does not start properly, but remains in a status of "Starting" for about 7 minutes and 38 seconds, and then fails.

My web application works fine when the service is in the "Starting" mode.

I have a windows scheduled task that runs every minute to restart the service if necessary.

```
net start "my service"
```

Therefore there is a gap of about 22 seconds from when the service fails until it starts up again. In additional it takes an additional 30 seconds or so for my application (which is dependent on this service) to start working.

I have intentionally not named the errant service.  I did open a separate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470975/oracle-oc4j-service-keeps-stopping whose aim was to actually solve the problem.

In this question, I am not trying to solve the problem, but rather find a workaround to try and keep this service in a status of "Starting" the whole time.

What is infuriating, is that until I restarted the server today, my workaround of restarting the service every 3 minutes actually worked, with no application downtime whatsoever.

Does anybody have any suggestions?  I did try changing the registry key of ServicesPipeTimeout to 86400000 (24 hours!) in a bid to keep the service in the status of "Starting" for longer.

Comment: Service should be in the state RUNNING, rather than Starting. Starting is a transitional state [(more info on MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee126211(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Thank you Seva Titov. I admit this is not an optimal situation, but the application works even in the "Starting" mode. (BTW I think you mean "Started" rather than "Running." )

Comment: 'sc query <service_name>' reports RUNNING for started service. However the name is not important. Service cannot be for a long time in Starting state, SCM will kill it eventually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found a possible solution to my problem that I am very uneasy about...

I downloaded WinDbg from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8279

I opened WinDbg and did Attach to Process, and selected my service.

As long as WinDbg is open, it seems to "hold" the process and prevent it from stopping.

How long it will continue to do so, remains to be seen, but it has held for over half an hour now (whereas before the service stopped after 8 minutes)

Comment: This solution held for nearly a year until I did an entire system upgrade!

Answer (score 3):

If you have the timeout set to 24 hours and the service does not start or stay in 'starting' mode , then it must be either crashing or closing itself down.

If you want to try to restarting your service immediately it crashes, then, on the properties of your service, select the 'Recovery' tab. You should be able to set the service to restart on first, second and subsequent failures and set the service to restart after 0 minutes,

Note, this will not work if windows thinks that the service is closing down properly.

It should go without saying that this is a last resort only if you can't get whoever wrote the service to fix the problems.

Comment: Hi Sgmoore. Thank you for your advice about the Restart.  This didn't work (presumably because the service, as you write, did not close down properly - or in my case, never started properly)

Comment: Actually, if the service did **not** close down properly it **should** restart immediately. If it closed properly, then it assumes the service is being deliberately shut down and does not restart. If the service is 'starting' then they should be no need to restart it.

Comment: Should point out, just in case you misunderstood me, this is not designed to make the service start properly or to stay starting, but merely to restart immediately after it crashes. There is unfortunately no magic button or setting that can make a buggy program stop crashing, which is why you need to get the people who wrote the service to look at the problem.

Comment: Hi sgmoore. Thanks for your clarifications.  However I am not entirely convinced that the service is crashing, but rather being closed externally, which is why windbg (see my answer I gave below) seems to hold it open.

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying 'Restart the Service' for all three sections on the Recovery tab, but that will only work if the service is ending abnormally.

Our company faced a similar problem and we developed [Service Protector](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/ServiceProtector/), a commercial application that can babysit a service and keep it running 24/7. It may work in your situation too.

Comment: Thank you CoreTech. I am currently trying Service Protector.  (BTW I sent important feedback about this to your company. Please let me know if you didn't get it.) [The Restart The Service on Recovery tab didn't work]  Service Protector does restart the service immediately (which is an advantage on my script which only checks every minute) however my application falls in those few seconds that the service is restarting, so I would ideally like to prevent the service from stopping rather than immediately restarting it.